# Resource management in python

Tags: python

I have an external resource that can be created and destroyed by application. Python class wraps handle to this resource in a straightforward way.

```
import interop

class Resource:

    def __init__(self, *params):
        self.__handle = interop.create_handle(*params)

    def destroy(self):
        if self.__handle:
            interop.destroy_handle(self.__handle)
            self.__handle = None
```

So far so good everything seems clear. But what if we want to ensure that `destroy` method was called? Obviously we can add `__del__` method:

```
    def __del__(self):
        self.destroy()
```

This works most of the time except the cases when I'm trying to create global variables of this class. For global object destruction order is undefined in python, so module `interop` can be destroyed earlier then `Resource` object. If this is the case one can get a stacktrace during program shutdown.

I want this code to work in any scenario so I wrap `destroy` call with the `try - except`:

```
    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.destroy()
        except:
            pass
```

Now I can use `Resource` instances as globals but at the same time I can lose some error information. I don't want this to happen but I can't log error message inside the `__del__` method because `logging` module can be unloaded first during program shutdown. Maybe it is better to keep going without try-except here? What can you suggest?

Comment: You can except only the specific error that you are wanting to catch, i.e., the one that happens when you don't have the try: block.

Comment: Are you aware of `with` and [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html)?

Comment: Do you really need globals? You can pass resources as parameters where they are needed.

Comment: I know about context managers and `with` statement and plan to use them. At the same time I want to deal with improper use of my library (and yes, this is a library and user might want to use globals).

Comment: @mdurant yes, but maybe it is better to leave everything as is, because getting this exception means that there is a resource leak in a program?